# Android images confusion?

Tags: android

I have say 30 images in my android app. And as per android's documents I should have images for all screen resolution i.e. I should have drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawble-hdpi etc.

Does this mean that I will end up having and asking the user to download 30*4=120 images, or does the android platform check before uploading and only uploads the images supported for that particular phone?

Is there any nice and easy way to handle these images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you need to include all those images, if you want your app to have nice UI on all screen sizes and resolutions. You can also choose to target your app only on specific screens, and declare that in the manifest. Users with screens that don't match your requirements will not see your app on the market then. However, this is probably not what you want.

As for the future, google knows about this problem and announced that it will support creating separate .apk for different kinds of devices, so in the future, this will be the way to go for apps with big sizes. Search google for "multiple apk support" for more info.

Comment: too bad :( It makes my app too heavy. Anyway thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Those are for the on device images (app icons, menu item icons, splash screen image).

It sounds like you are having your users download some additional images themselves, so why don't you download only the images needed for their specific screen resolution.  That way, you can even have better control over the quality of the images, as you can go by actual screen resolution rather than by hdpi, mdpi, or ldpi.

Comment: What do you mean by on device images? I am providing these icons and splash images, plus I need some more images for my flashcard app. So how can i mange them easily? Apologies for dumb question, but i m trying to learn android programming here.

Comment: The on device images are listed after in parenthesis.  I will repeat them here: app icons, menu item icons, splash screen images.  Those are the images that you would supply multiples of bundled with your application in the drawable-mdpi, -ldpi, -hdpi.  If you have additional images to download, you do not need to send multiples of each file.  You should be able to download only the ones you need based on the screen resolution of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically get android to create images for their device from a master image.

I don't think there's an alternative, there's no way to supply a different app to a user based on their device specs, other than API version.